# cannot install "LemmatizerPrebuiltCompact" library for .net - visual studio error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, dll, lemmatization, sharpnlp

I am trying to use `Lemmatizer` in my asp.net code (c#). To do that, I should install 4 libraries, which are:
`LemmaSharp`, `LemmaSharpPrebuilt`, `Lzma#` and `LemmatizerPrebuiltCompact`

I had found the first 3 libraries on `NuGet`, but I can't find `LemmatizerPrebuiltCompact` library. Thus, when I write the following code:

```
ILemmatizer lmtz = new LemmatizerPrebuiltCompact(LemmaSharp.LanguagePrebuilt.English);
```

I got the following error on `LemmatizerPrebuiltCompact` as expected:

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'LemmatizerPrebuiltCompact'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

**Try #1**

I try to install `LemmatizerPrebuiltCompact.dll` library and add it the project, but when I change the directory of the project it was gone (PS: I want it to work either the project directory was changed). Thus, I try to add it again but I cannot. Moreover I got the following error:

> The reference is invalid or unsupported

**Try #2**

So, I try to install `Sparc.TagCloud` library. When I do that, the first error is gone, but it is showing error on `LemmaSharp.LanguagePrebuilt.English`:

> Error CS0433  The type 'LanguagePrebuilt' exists in both
>   'LemmaSharpPreBuilt, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' and 'LemmaSharpPrebuilt, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' myMLAppML.ConsoleApp

I think that this error has appeared since Sparc.TagCloud version was 0.0.1, Although, LemmaSharp version was 1.0.1.

What's the problem?

Does anyone have any idea what I can do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had solved the `The reference is invalid or unsupported` error by putting the `DLL library` into the main directory of the project